# SharePoint 2013 Partial Security on the page

Tags: listview, sharepoint, calendar

This is in SharePoint 2013.
I have a calendar App in a sub site that has permissions to all Owners, Designers but not to Visitors. Basically visitors can not see the calendar. The Sub site has permissions to all including the Visitors as well. I placed this calendar on the Home page of the sub site as a Webpart. 
It is fine without any problems anytime the owners and designers visit the page, but when Visitors visit the page it is throwing error like below. So Site has permissions to view except the Calendar which is also on the page.

My expectation is...the page should come up to the visitor, but hide the Calendar.

That is not what happening, instead...it is throwing the error like below.

What am I missing here?
 [image]

Thanks in advance
-Satyen

Comment: The error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an objects" tells us that your calendar app throws and exception. Can you show us the code of your calendar app? You can also try debugging it to find where it throws the exception